# how to filter array with another array containing more than one element

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I have an array of objects array1[1,2,3,4,5]. array2[3,4]. I need to get array1 filtering out elements from array2. Below code works as long as array2 has one element. If it has more than one, its not filtering out. What am I doing wrong.

this.array1 = this.array1.filter(item => this.array2.some(f => f !== item));

Comment: ist the language python?

Comment: no, using angular 4

Comment: its simple. this.array1 = this.array1.filter(item => this.array2.indexOf(item) === -1);

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
 this.array1 = this.array1.filter(item => !this.array2.some(f => f == item));
```